# Filter DateTimeField Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API with the django rest framework.
I have this model:

```
class Versement(models.Model):
     date = models.DateTimeField()
     organisme = models.ForeignKey(Organisme, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This is my view:

```
class VersementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Versement.objects.all()
     serializer_class = VersementSerializer
     pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
     filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
     filter_class = VersementFilter
     search_fields = ('organisme__nom', 'organisme__code')
```

And my filter:

```
class VersementFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Versement
        fields = ['organisme__id']
```

Is it possible to add the field "date" to my fields and only search for a special year ? For example:

```
{{URL}}/versements/?date=2015
```

If you guys know how to proceed...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define filter field explicitly and specify `lookup_expr='year'`:

```
class VersementFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')

    class Meta:
        model = Versement
        fields = ['organisme__id', 'date']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.
Can I have a link to the doc ?